# Was wondering what type of tree this was

Tags: trees

Small/Medium tree had small nice smelling flowers and now had some type of fruit. Possibly pear but looks like small apples[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without a picture of it...

Comment: Please send us a picture or two?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pear for sure. Maybe [Red Williams](http://www.dtbrownseeds.co.uk/Fruit-Trees_2/Pear-Trees/Pear-Tree-Red-Williams_2.html#.Wz3IKYp9iUk), I think the fruits will grow a bit bigger (for Northern hemisphere pear harvest is late August to September).